# Changing the encoding of ALL files

Tags: eclipse

How can I change the encoding of all files in the project? I've been always just going to properties -> text file encoding -> other (utf-8). However it doesn't work for some files with "exotic" extentions such as .twig.html. How can I do this for all files regardless to their extentions?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't change the encoding of those files, it only changes the encoding Eclipse will use when reading/writing those files.  For files like *.html where the file actually has a way to declare the correct encoding in its own contents, have it do that.